# Compare with start date and end date in ios

Tags: ios, date

In my ViewController having 2 TextFields start date and end date.
I am using UIDatePicker accessing the Textfield value every thing is fine.
But I want Check Start date always less or equal End dates.
Please any one help me.. I'm sincerely appreciate with you.

```
@interface: UIViewController
{
}
UIDatePicker *itsDatePicker1;
UIDatePicker *itsDatePicker2;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *checkInDateTxtFld;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *checkOutDateTxtFld;
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (self.activeTextFld)
    {
        [self.activeTextFld resignFirstResponder];
    }
    self.activeTextFld=textField;

    if (textField.tag==12)
    {

        UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        toolbar.barStyle   = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

        UIBarButtonItem *itemDone  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self.checkInDateTxtFld action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)];
        UIBarButtonItem *itemSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

        toolbar.items = @[itemSpace,itemDone];

        itsDatePicker1= [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
        itsDatePicker1.minimumDate   = [NSDate date];
        itsDatePicker1.date          = [NSDate date];
        [itsDatePicker1 addTarget:self action:@selector(incidentDateValueChanged1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        self.checkInDateTxtFld.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
        self.checkInDateTxtFld.inputView          = itsDatePicker1;
    }
    else if (textField.tag==13)
    {
        UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        toolbar.barStyle   = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

        UIBarButtonItem *itemDone  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self.checkOutDateTxtFld action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)];
        UIBarButtonItem *itemSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

        toolbar.items = @[itemSpace,itemDone];

        itsDatePicker2= [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
        itsDatePicker2.minimumDate   = [NSDate date];
        itsDatePicker2.date          = [NSDate date];
        [itsDatePicker2 addTarget:self action:@selector(incidentDateValueChanged2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        self.checkOutDateTxtFld.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
        self.checkOutDateTxtFld.inputView = itsDatePicker2;
    }
    else if (textField.tag==14)
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        self.selctedPickerType=CHECK_NO_OF_ROOMS;
        [self showPicker];
    }
}

- (IBAction) incidentDateValueChanged1:(id)sender
{
    dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   // [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];

    self.checkInDateTxtFld.text = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:[itsDatePicker1 date]];
}

- (IBAction) incidentDateValueChanged2:(id)sender
{
    dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //  [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    self.checkOutDateTxtFld.text = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:[itsDatePicker2 date]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple just check it with date

> date1 and date2 both are the object of NSDate. one have value of Todays date and another is your's given date. and simple compare it by

```
        if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedSame) {
            return YES;
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
```

Comment: Or more concisely `return [date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedSame;`.

Comment: yep its optimised......;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is Newer than date2");
} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the Equal");
}
```